# Поиск по регулярным выражениям C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день!

Есть текст судебного содержания, который я загнал в строку. Текст в какой то мере шаблонный, как и большинство судебных заключений\постановлений.

К примеру меня интересует ФИО ответчика, оно содержится практически всегда между фраз "с иском к" %тут ФИО% "о взыскании".

Подскажите как должно выглядеть регулярное выражения для подобного случая на C#.

Comment: Самое простое - `с иском к (.+ .+ .+) о взыскании` , улучшать можно до бесконечности

Comment: А не подскажите как ваш пример будет выглядеть в синтаксисе регулярных выражений? Я с ними совсем на вы, увы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var match = new Regex("с иском к (.+) о взыскании").Match(text);
if (match.Success)
{
     var fio = match.Groups[1].Value;
     Console.WriteLine($"ФИО ответчика: {fio}");
}
```

Comment: string test = "с иском к Чебурашке К.Р. о взыскании";
            

            var match = new Regex("с иском к (.+ .+ .+) о взыскании").Match(test);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var fio = match.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine($"ФИО ответчика: {fio}");
            }

Спасибо за отклик, но, к сожалению, почему то в тестовой строке ничего не находит. D:

Comment: исправил, давайте попробуем не учитывать пробелы

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заработало, все отлично находит.